# How to implement Mahalanobis Distance in Matlab for Eigenfaces

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance, mahalanobis

I'm trying to implement the Eigenfaces algorithm and was able to check if a face matches by checking the euclidean distance as shown below. I would like to improve the code using Mahalanobis Distance instead.

```
similarity_score = arrayfun(@(n) 1 / (1 + norm(features(:,n) - feature_vec)), 1:num_images);
```

where `features` is a table containing a feature in each column and `feature_vec` is the feature vector we're checking.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. Right now im wondering what the question is.

Comment: Improved grammar.